# Convert AJAX script to jQuery syntax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple AJAX script that, when a select menu option is made, queries a PHP page for some values from a database and inserts this into elements in the form. I've been asked to convert this to jQuery syntax to make it consistent with the rest of the site but being new to jQuery I'm getting stuck.

Here's the form element at the moment:

```html
<div class="input-group col-xs-8">
  <select class="form-control" name="templateRef" id="templateRef" onchange="getTemplate(this.value)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="123">Template A</option>
    <option value="456">Template A</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and here's the AJAX script:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function getTemplate(str) {
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("messageBody").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById("messageBody").innerHTML = data[i].templateBody;
          document.getElementById("emailSubject").value = data[i].templateSubject;
        }
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "getTemplate?templateID=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  } < /script>
```

Comment: What are you getting stuck on?

Comment: Do you understand that you overwrite the `innerHTML` and `value`in your loop?

Comment: That's not an "AJAX script", it's JavaScript that's doing an AJAX request using native JavaScript instead of a framework (like jQuery). I'd suggest reading the jQuery documentation, it's pretty good, and there are probably thousands of jQuery tutorials out there and millions of examples.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the code to be jQuery-style:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: 'getTemplate?templateID=' + str,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
    $(data).each(function() {
        $("#messageBody").html(this.templateBody);
        $("#emailSubject").val(this.templateSubject);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTemplate(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("messageBody").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "getTemplate?templateID=" + str,
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("messageBody").innerHTML = data[i].templateBody;
                document.getElementById("emailSubject").value = data[i].templateSubject;
            }
        }
    });
}
```